# Generic method input generic Objects of type

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, generic-programming

I am refactoring code... Considering this chain of inheritance...

`public class Base`

`public class Simple extends Base`

`public class Secure extends Simple`

`public class Framework extends Secure`

`public class Application extends Framework`

and the class

`public class ApplicationCallback`

Currently, `ApplicationCallback` has this method `public abstract ApplicationCallback#doSomething(Application app)`, but I want it to be accessible by `Base`.... without changing the code everywhere from `ApplicationCallback#doSomething(Application app)` to `ApplicationCallback#doSomething(Base base)`.

Is there a way I can define a method that I can define to prevent the code change everywhere?

Kind of like `ApplicationCallback#doSomething(T<? extends Base> app)`, so that when overriding, I can just put `ApplicationCallback#doSomething(Base base)` and `ApplicationCallback#doSomething(Simple simple)` etc etc.

The question is about `@Override ApplicationCallback#doSomething()`

Comment: That looks like an awefully deep inheritance hierarchy, I doubt that's a good idea. Also, it's not clear to me what you mean by "accessible by `Base`".

Comment: "*without changing the code everywhere from `ApplicationCallback#doSomething(Application app)` to  `ApplicationCallback#doSomething(Base base)`*" - You wouldn't have to change the calling sides since you widen the parameter type from `Application` to `Base`.

Comment: @Turing85 When using `@Override`, it would have to be changed to `ApplicationCallback#doSomething(Base base)`. Is there a way to make it generic so that anything that extends `Base` is acceptable in the method input?

Comment: as @Turing85 said if you change the definition to doSomething(Base base) it will work for anything that extends Base. However if you want to strongly type doSomething you need to add a generic to the class definition. ApplicationCallback<T extends Base> { doSomething(T base)}

Comment: No. I am trying to override `ApplicationCallback`

Comment: @user3635998 you will have to change some code in order to get type safety.

Answer (score 1):

You should introduce a generic parameter on the `ApplicationCallback` class. That allows you to define callbacks that take only certain subtypes:

`class Callback<T extends Base> { abstract void doSomething(T t); }`

That would allow you to use methods from the subtype you defined, for example if the `Secure` class adds a `getSecureThing()` feature, you could:

```
Callback<Base> base = new Callback<Base>() { 
  void doSomething(Base base) {
    // getSecureThing not available
  }
}
Callback<Application> app = new Callback<Application>() { 
  void doSomething(Application app) {
    // app.getSecureThing is available
  }
}
```

Comment: This does require you to change all `Callback` implementations. If you're using IntelliJ, it has a feature called 'introduce type parameter' that will help you do that automatically.

Comment: If you need the generic parameter only on the `doSomething(...)`-method, only set this method generic: `public <T extends Base> abstract void doSomething(T t);`

Comment: That won't work. Try to implement it and actually call the callbacks - you'll see why.

Comment: Then my testcase seems to be missing something. It compiles and runs for me. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: @Turing85 Try to call the `getSecureThing` method from my example in a callback. It won't be available, because you can't force the callback implementation to only take `Secure` instances.

Comment: I operated under the assumption that OP needs only access to `Base`, not to the concrete type (thus, s/he wants to refactor the code). Under the assumption that OP needs access to the specific type, you are right =)

Comment: Then you won't need a generic type at all - `class Callback { void doSomething(Base base); }` will do just fine.

Comment: That was my first comment to the question. OP responded that s/he does not want to do so since s/he would have to change the parameter in all overriding methods as well.